# wrong translation in admin/structure/views

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a multi language site with Drupal 8.7.4
and default language is English.

when i go to en/admin/structure/views i see list of views in English language. if i go to french interface via fr/admin/structure/views i expect to see list of views in french words for example i expect to see 'Surveillance' instead of 'watchdog' but i see all views name in English.

Config Translation is enabled and french translation for view's name is available.

Comment: Do you have Interface translation enabled? Is French translated (what is the % of strings translated)?

Comment: @prkos yes, and 99.57%.  i have a new idea that view's and menu's name are shown always in language with which we install site no matter what language interface we use. in my case site is installed with english language. am i right?

Comment: No, it can all be translated. Have you tried rebuilding the cache?

Comment: @prkos yes.i tried it.

Comment: @prkos. this is weird. i  installed umami food demo fresh. with spanish language result is same. the whole of interface is in spanish and translation for watchdog, Guardián is available  but all views names are shown in english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Views list is a config entity list and these are listed override free:

*ConfigEntityListBuilder::load*

```
  public function load() {
    $entity_ids = $this->getEntityIds();
    $entities = $this->storage->loadMultipleOverrideFree($entity_ids);

    // Sort the entities using the entity class's sort() method.
    // See \Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase::sort().
    uasort($entities, [$this->entityType->getClass(), 'sort']);
    return $entities;
  }
```

This is intentional. The pros and cons are discussed in these issues:

[Config entity admin lists show configuration with overrides (eg. localized)](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2136559)

[Menu overview always shows the untranslated config entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2872646)

Comment: I didn't know about these issues. IMHO this is a bad usability decision

Comment: i was trying to read all comments of two mentioned links but honestly i didn't get why there is a decision to don't show view or menu name in current interface language. as @Ismail Cherri and others on those links said this implementation is not good at all. is this issue going to fix at all?

Comment: Not likely to happen in the near future. The docs were updated as well to explain the reasons for this decision, see https://www.drupal.org/project/user_guide/issues/2959852

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue in a fresh Drupal 8.7.5 installation.
I reported the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3068831) in Drupal core issue tracker.

Also, here are a screenshot in which French Views names are displayed in an English interface:
[image]

Comment: thanks.  actually i don't remember with 
which version of drupal i insalled my site. I updated it to 8.7 later. So problem is not about 8.7